# Python - formatting of bar charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

Re the bar chart created using the python library matplotlib.pyplot I have three questions:

1. How can I format the grid such that the vertical gridlines do not cut through the bars but are positioned between the bars?
2. How can I position the value labels always on top of the bar?
3. How can I control the size of the big margin on the left side of the first bar?
4. The value displayed as bar label is the sum of ysizes_base and ysizes_add; I expected only the value from ysizes_add. How do I achieve that?

The code reads

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

ysizes_base = [0, 2850, 3403, 3803, 4043, 4273, 4499, 4699, 4848, 4958, 5042, 5122, 5195, 5265, 5328, 5373, 5408, 5433, 5458, 5481, 5491, 5486, 5481, 5475, 5465, 5455, 5445, 5435, 5425, 5408, 5388, 5367, 5342, 5312, 5273, 5233, 5193, 5152, 5102, 5047, 4992, 4927, 4862, 4796, 4696, 4596, 4486, 4361, 4206, 4036]
ysizes_add = [2850, 553, 400, 240, 230, 226, 200, 149, 110, 84, 80, 73, 70, 63, 45, 35, 25, 25, 23, 10, -5, -5, -6, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -17, -20, -21, -25, -30, -39, -40, -40, -41, -50, -55, -55, -65, -65, -66, -100, -100, -110, -125, -155, -170, -175]
short_texts = ['Rx', 'Ca', 'AP', 'Br', 'RM', 'VCA', 'Tu', 'He', 'Cha', 'Cho', 'PP', 'VC', 'BP', 'Gu', 'Di', 'FPJ', 'Hu', 'RD', 'Ze', 'AL', 'Or', 'ML', 'HW', 'IWC', 'FM', 'GO', 'BR', 'Mo', 'OP', 'Ce', 'BM', 'Ha', 'FC', 'Pi', 'UN', 'CFB', 'JLC', 'Mi', 'Mo', 'CKW', 'Vi', 'Ti', 'Sw', 'Bu', 'Ra', 'Lo', 'Br', 'Om', 'Ti', 'TH']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12, 12 / math.sqrt(2.0)))

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize='small', colors='gray', labelrotation=90.0)
   
ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.1 * max(ysizes_base)]) # w/o 1.1 the labels do not fit 

ax.grid(visible=True) 

ax.set_xticks(range(len(ysizes_base)), labels=short_texts)

abx = ax.bar(range(len(ysizes_base)), height=ysizes_add, bottom=ysizes_base, color='blue', align='center')

ax.bar_label(abx, label_type='edge', padding=5.0, rotation=90.0, fontsize=6, color='gray')

plt.show()
```

Re (1) I also tried `abx = ax.bar(..., align='edge')` but that sends the bar to the left edge (as expected).

Re (2) I checked `label_type='center'` but it does only support `'edge', 'center'`.

[image]

Comment: done; I changed the code accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below makes the following changes:

- Introducing numpy to enable [array expressions](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/)
- Converting negative heights to positive heights (and changing the base where necessary).  That way, the bar texts will always be placed on top.
- Introducing minor ticks for the x-axis, and use these to draw the grid lines.
- Less unused space at the left and right via `ax.margins(x=...)`
- Centering the y tick labels.
- Removing the spines around the plot, as they don't go well with so many grid lines.
- Removing the tick marks with `ax.tick_params(..., length=0)`.
- Calling `ax.bar()` earlier (this kind of plotting function might change the ticks and other visual aspects).

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

ysizes_base = [0, 2850, 3403, 3803, 4043, 4273, 4499, 4699, 4848, 4958, 5042, 5122, 5195, 5265, 5328, 5373, 5408, 5433,
               5458, 5481, 5491, 5486, 5481, 5475, 5465, 5455, 5445, 5435, 5425, 5408, 5388, 5367, 5342, 5312, 5273,
               5233, 5193, 5152, 5102, 5047, 4992, 4927, 4862, 4796, 4696, 4596, 4486, 4361, 4206, 4036]
ysizes_add = [2850, 553, 400, 240, 230, 226, 200, 149, 110, 84, 80, 73, 70, 63, 45, 35, 25, 25, 23, 10, -5, -5, -6, -10,
              -10, -10, -10, -10, -17, -20, -21, -25, -30, -39, -40, -40, -41, -50, -55, -55, -65, -65, -66, -100, -100,
              -110, -125, -155, -170, -175]
ysizes_base = np.array(ysizes_base)  # convert to numpy to allow vectorized notation
ysizes_add = np.array(ysizes_add)

short_texts = ['Rx', 'Ca', 'AP', 'Br', 'RM', 'VCA', 'Tu', 'He', 'Cha', 'Cho', 'PP', 'VC', 'BP', 'Gu', 'Di', 'FPJ', 'Hu',
               'RD', 'Ze', 'AL', 'Or', 'ML', 'HW', 'IWC', 'FM', 'GO', 'BR', 'Mo', 'OP', 'Ce', 'BM', 'Ha', 'FC', 'Pi',
               'UN', 'CFB', 'JLC', 'Mi', 'Mo', 'CKW', 'Vi', 'Ti', 'Sw', 'Bu', 'Ra', 'Lo', 'Br', 'Om', 'Ti', 'TH']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 12 / math.sqrt(2.0)))

abx = ax.bar(range(len(ysizes_base)),
             height=np.abs(ysizes_add),
             bottom=np.where(ysizes_add < 0, ysizes_base + ysizes_add, ysizes_base),
             color='cornflowerblue', align='center')

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize='small', colors='gray', labelrotation=90.0, length=0)
ax.set_ylim([0.0, 1.1 * max(ysizes_base)])  # w/o 1.1 the labels do not fit
ax.grid(visible=True, axis='y', which='major')
ax.grid(visible=True, axis='x', which='minor')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(ysizes_base)), labels=short_texts)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(ysizes_base) + 1) - 0.5, minor=True)
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), va='center')

ax.bar_label(abx, label_type='edge', padding=5.0, rotation=90.0, fontsize=6, color='gray')
ax.margins(x=0.01)  # less unused space left and right
for sp in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[sp].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with gridlines between bars]

Comment: There's another issue which I overlooked so for, namely the value that is displayd! I added this as topic (4) to the original question.

Comment: You can change the labels as an additional parameter to `bar_label`, e.g. `ax.bar_label(abx, labels=ysizes_add, ...)`.

Comment: thx again; @myslef: RTFM - so stupid ;-)

Comment: the most helpfful idea was to use np.where() in the charts ... now everything is possible ;-)